# subversion error

Tags: asp.net, svn

we are 5 members woh are working in same project.for integration we are using subversion.
now we r getting the error
Error65 Files has invalid value "<<<<<<< .mine". Illegal characters in path.    MaxnetEcommerceNew
MaxnetEcommerceNew is our folder name
we tried to search for "<<<<<<< .mine". but there is no such text present in our project.
can u help me

Comment: You haven't mentioned svn client tool you are using!
Tortoise SVN Client is very useful tool... have a look

http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/
Resolving conflict
http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-conflicts.html

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have an unresolved conflict.

Open the conflicted file and resolve it.

Comment: After editing the file and saving a working copy, don't forget `svn resolved <filename>`.

Answer (score 3):

<<<<<<<<<.mine means that part was your changes. Then you will also see RXX . That is called revisions. For example, if you have R64, then at  Revision 64 the code was that. So you  need to resolve the conflict by opting Resolve Conflicts option from your SVN Client. In future , to avoid such things take control of the files before editing and release all controls of the file after committing so that other guy can work on next revision. It happens when both commits the same file at the same time. So the svn arises conflict issue. You also remove those manually but need some SVN experts of your organization.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing the command
`svn status`
in  your terminal, while you are in your local repository.

This will list the version control status of the files. Find the file which has the letter "C", in the leftmost column. That file is the file in which the conflict occurs.